# Aggregate undetermined number of files for all wildcards in one rule

Tags: snakemake

I have a set of files which will be individually processed to produce multiple files.  Exactly how many files is unknown before runtime.  (If it matters, this is demultiplexing DNA sequencing results.)  I then have a script which takes all of these files at once.

Right now I have something like this:

```py
checkpoint demultiplex:
    input: "{sample}.fastq"
    output: directory("{sample}")
    shell:
        # in reality the number of output files is not known
        "mkdir -p {output} &&"
        "touch {output}/{wildcards.sample}-1.fastq &&"
        "touch {output}/{wildcards.sample}-2.fastq &&"
        "touch {output}/{wildcards.sample}-3.fastq"

def find_outputs(wildcards) :
    outdir = checkpoints.demultiplex.get(**wildcards)
    return glob.glob("{sample}/{sample}-*.fastq".format_map(wildcards))

rule analysis:
    input: find_outputs
    outputs: "results.txt"
    script: "scripts/do_analysis.R"
```

This obviously doesn't work, because the values of `{sample}` (Assume they should be A, B, C, D) are never defined.

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing the question, I came up with this answer, which seems to work.  However, if you have something cleaner, I would be happy to accept it!

For `checkpoints.<rule>.get()` to work its magic, it has to be in the body of a function which is given as a reference, not called.  Also, this function needs to take one argument, wildcards.

So we make a function that returns closures having the behavior we need. The value of wildcards (which will be empty in this case) is ignored, allowing us to specify the values manually.

```py
def find_outputs(sample):
    def f(wildcards):
        checkpoints.demultiplex.get(sample = sample)
        return glob.glob("{sample}/{sample}-*.fastq".format(sample = sample))
    return f

rule analysis:
    input:
        find_outputs("A"),
        find_outputs("B"),
        find_outputs("C"),
        find_outputs("D")
    output: "results.txt"
    script: "script/do_analysis.R"
```

Comment: One disadvantage of this solution is that it requires the sample names to be written explicitly, rather than given in a config file.